# Use KeyTime value as resource

Tags: wpf, animation, resources

I have the storyboard:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="St1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBlue">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

I will like to extract the keyTime value and place it somewhere. In other words I been trying to make this work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <sys:TimeSpan x:Key="FadeInBeginTime">0:0:2</sys:TimeSpan>
    <Duration x:Key="FadeInDuration">0:0:1</Duration>

    <Storyboard x:Key="St1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="imageBlue">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime={StaticResource FadeInDuration}" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

note I am using the namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

for some reason that does not work

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the FadeInDuration as a KeyTime not a TimeSpan

i.e:

```
<KeyTime x:Key="FadeInBeginTime">0:0:2.0</KeyTime>
```